# Error Callback when call interval in class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create interval in my js class, the code like below :

```
class Clock {

constructor(template) { 
  this.template = template;
  this.timer = this.timer;
  this.date = new Date(); // call date
}

render = () => {

  let hours = this.date.getHours(); // get hours
  if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
  let minutes = this.date.getMinutes(); // get minutes
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
  let seconds = this.date.getSeconds(); // get seconds
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;

  let output = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds; 

  return output; // output
}

stop = () => { // stop interval
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}

start = () => { // start interval
  this.timer = setInterval(this.render(), 1000);
}

}

var clock = new Clock({template: ''});
clock.start();
```

and I have error like this :

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received '06:16:49'
at setInterval (timers.js:166:3)
at Clock.start (/home/runner/Training/index.js:28:20)
at /home/runner/Training/index.js:33:7
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:209:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

I think the problem is when I call `this.timer = setInterval(this.render(), 1000);` but when i change to `this.timer = setInterval(this.render, 1000);` the error will show like this **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined**, I tried to figure out, but I can't solve the problem because I just new learn this javascript. So can anyone help me please.
thank you.

Comment: `this.render` is a function; `this.render()` _calls_ the function; `setInterval` expects a function.

Comment: @elclanrs i try to use this.render, but the error show like this **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined**

Comment: `setInterval(this.render.bnid(this), 1000);`

Comment: this.timer = setInterval(this.render, 1000); - pass the render function. Dont execute it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

---

**setInterval** is expecting a callback function. You shouldn't execute it.

```
start =() => {
     this.timer = setInterval(() => this.render(), 1000);
   }

class Clock {

  constructor(template) {
    this.template = template;
    this.timer = this.timer;
   // this.date = new Date(); // call date
  }

  render = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours(); // get hours
    if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
    let minutes = date.getMinutes(); // get minutes
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
    let seconds = date.getSeconds(); // get seconds
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;

    let output = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

    console.log(output)

    return output; // output
  }

  stop = () => { // stop interval
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  start = () => { // start interval
    this.timer = setInterval(this.render, 1000);
  }

}

var clock = new Clock({ template: '' });
clock.start();
```

Comment: what shoud i call render? because i want to call time every second and always increase time second

Comment: This won't work in `this` context. @Agung did my solution not for you?

Comment: @Agung - why can't you access `new Date()` directly into your render method ?

Comment: @Sarun UK, maybe you should delete render() to render in startInterval. Because the problem is, first when i call function in startInterval, second when i call new Date() in construct

Comment: @SILENT yes not work, but he gave me a clue so yg fix my code with myself. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

There were couple issues with your code but try the following:

```
class Clock {
  constructor(template) {
    this.template = template;
    this.date = new Date(); // call date
  }

  render() {
    let hours = this.date.getHours(); // get hours
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    let minutes = this.date.getMinutes(); // get minutes
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    let seconds = this.date.getSeconds(); // get seconds
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    let output = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    return output; // output
  }

  stop() {
    // stop interval
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  start() {
    // start interval
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.render(), 1000);
  }
}

const clock = new Clock("");
clock.start();
```

Your constructor was improperly set (but also unused) and your `this` reference was off.

Live sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clock-test-1r8dm?file=/src/index.js

---

Based off comments made by OP, OP may be asking for time to increment. If so, replace render with

```
  render() {
    const nD = new Date();
    let hours = nD.getHours(); // get hours
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    let minutes = nD.getMinutes(); // get minutes
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    let seconds = nD.getSeconds(); // get seconds
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    let output = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    return output; // output
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval accepts the name of the function

```
class Clock {
  constructor(template) {
    this.template = template;
    this.timer = this.timer;
    this.date = new Date();
  }

  render = () =>  {
    let time = this.date;
    let hours = time.getHours();
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    let minutes = time.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    let seconds = time.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;

    let output = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    console.log(output);
  }

  stop = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  start =() => {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.render, 1000);
  }
}

var clock = new Clock({ template: "" });
clock.start();
```

Comment: if i use this, the error will show like this **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined**

Comment: When i ran this , it was working fine in my machine. There might be some other mistake in your code. check if this.date is undefined or not

Comment: where can i check that? because that's all my code have

Comment: check this code "this.date = new Date()". If you are using vs code , then hover over it and see if it is undefined or not

Comment: i check it and undifined, what should i do?

Comment: could you please show me the screenshot? As i pasted your code in mine, so it should be working. I think you made some changes in your code. In order to figure out  what you are doing, would you please post a screenshot in imgur or any image sharing website ?

Comment: i just training to create single class. and want to call time every second in output. here the link [link](https://imgur.com/qnXuJNu)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval creates a new scope so `this` inside setInterval is not the same class instance  so `this.date.getHours()` will throw error since `this.date` will `undefined`.